# C# Monitor network send / rec help how to?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the network send / recieve bytes /s but it doen't give me any values.

[image]

```
PerformanceCounterCategory category = new PerformanceCounterCategory("Network Interface");
String[] instanceName = category.GetInstanceNames();
foreach (string ns in instanceName)
{
    PerformanceCounter netRecCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Received/sec", ns);
    PerformanceCounter netSentCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Network Interface", "Bytes Sent/sec", ns);
    LblSend.Text = ns;
    Console.WriteLine("Network Usage (Sent): {0}",
                   NetworkSend.Text = (netSentCounter.NextValue() + " Bytes/s").ToString());
    Console.WriteLine("Network Usage (Received): {0}",
                  LblRec.Text = (netRecCounter.NextValue() + " Bytes/s").ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine($"{netRecCounter.RawValue}");
```